# End After Start Input Form Onchange OnClick

Tags: javascript, html

I have to put two dates (Start and End of task).

I would like to guarantee that the user cannot send wrong data.

My problem is, after my possible solution, the user cannot type inside date_end.

I created two javascript to do this, but I'm not javascript experienced to be sure exactly how to do this.

```js
function datestart(value) {
  document.getElementById("date_end").value = value;
}

function dateend(value) {
  var vdatestart = document.getElementById("date_start").value;
  if (value < vdatestart) {
    document.getElementById("date_end").value = vdatestart;
  }
}
```

```css
.col-30 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-70 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name="form1" action="datetime1.php" method="post">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-30">
        <label>Start Date and Time from Start:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-70">
        <input type='datetime-local' name='date_start' id='date_start' min='2018-05-01T00:00' max='2018-05-22T08:00' required value='2018-05-22T08:00' onchange="datestart(this.value);" onclick="datestart(this.value);" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-30">
        <label>End Date and Time:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-70">
        <input type='datetime-local' name='date_end' id='date_end' min='2018-05-01T00:00' max='2018-05-22T08:00' required value='2018-05-22T08:00' onchange="dateend(this.value);" onclick="dateend(this.value);" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is not related to PHP which is not doing anything except setting the vars. I create a snippet for you. I am not sure what it is not doing that you want it to do

Comment: Thank you... Change Start and try to change End typing.

Comment: Seemingly works as expected on Chrome

Comment: If you change again Start...End stops to typing...